# Star Trek: Have objectionable jobs been automated away?

Tags: star-trek

other questions about cashless society of humans but this seems to have been due to a philosophical change. but is it implied that technology makes it possible for all to have food and shelter even without working?

Comment: Earth is a garden paradise where people only work if they want to. Hate indolence? Go live on a terraformed world or a farming colony.

Comment: so this has been done by creating farming and cleaning robots? the enterprise does not seem to have robots at all although there are of course food replicators. i am pretty sure there are no members of the crew who are janitors although i have the vaguest memory of seeing someone doing manual labor aboard the ship -- could be wrong.

Comment: You don't need farms for sustenance food, only for luxury goods like Picard's vineyard. Everything else can be provided by replicators.

Comment: and other stuff? cleaning? i guess replicators eliminate need for delivering items? hospital workers? who cares for mentally ill people who might be violent or has this been medically eliminated? is there euthanasia?

Comment: Hospital and ship's Sickbays seem to be staffed by what we would refer to as degree students, [studying toward becoming doctors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_Chapel).

Comment: Euthanasia exists in the Federation (q.v Vulcans) but humans don't seem to practice it, except in extreme cases like McCoy's father.

Comment: okay but i think seeing cleaning bots would explain a lot. maybe given that we have them now makes their existence go without saying?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Cleaning droids appear to be ubiqitous in the Star Trek universe. They perform automated jobs like removing dust, uprighting objects and general maintenance. Apparently they wait until late at night in order to minimise the amount of disruption they cause.